# Yoast and permalink troubleshooting

Tags: permalinks, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

For first let me introduce what I've already discovered.

I don't know how Yoast calculates the permalink but it's non standard and that fact creates a lot of problems.

There are some filters to force Yoast to use the correct permalink:

```
add_filter('wpseo_canonical',       array(__CLASS__, 'yoast_change_seo_canonical'), 1, 1 );
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_url',   array(__CLASS__, 'yoast_change_seo_opengraph_url'), 10);
add_filter('wpseo_schema_article',  array(__CLASS__, 'example_change_article') );
add_filter('yoast_seo_development_mode', '__return_true' ); 

public static function yoast_change_seo_canonical( $canonical )
{
    if ( is_single() )
    {
        return get_permalink();
    }
    else
        return $canonical;
}

public static function yoast_change_seo_opengraph_url( $canonical )
{
    return get_permalink();
}

function example_change_article( $data )
{
    //YoastSEO()->context_memoizer;

    YoastSEO()->meta->for_current_page()->canonical = get_permalink();
    YoastSEO()->meta->for_current_page()->open_graph_url = get_permalink();
}
```

The last one doesn't work as I would expect.

Any suggestion? I've tried both to change the data in the context / memoizer, but also to use the filters.

Comment: The last one being example_change_article or yoast_seo_development_mode? I don't see any calls to `apply_filters( 'wpseo_schema_article'` in the plugin.

Comment: And for my curiosity what exactly is Yoast doing - what does the permalinks it generates look like, and what's wrong with them? How are they different to get_permalink()?

Comment: @Rup: I have found out many interesting things. The primary category is not a WP native feature, it's from Yoast plugin and it's saved as a post_meta information. If Yoast is installed to retrieve the primary category it can be used $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term($term, $post->ID);             $primary_term = get_term($wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term());

Comment: But if it returns null, then it depends on how the plugin choose the primary category... the one I am using made different choice from what I would have expected.

Comment: the situation is something like /medicine/dental/post.htm and /beauty/post.htm. In this post apperars in different categories and one has also subcatergories.. a bug mess..